# Java Jersey MongoDB GET sublist

Tags: java, mongodb, api, jersey

I am developing an API to get position list in a BSON looks like below.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59512a4ca33bc80248fb1435"),
"id" : NumberLong(1),
"locationId" : NumberLong(17),
"position" : [ 
    {
        "latitude" : 12342.0,
        "longitude" : 1232342.0,
        "time" : "on May 04 09:51:52 CDT 2009"
    }, 
    {
        "latitude" : 12342.0,
        "longitude" : 1232342.0,
        "time" : "on May 04 09:51:52 CDT 2009"
    }
    ]
}
```

In my Employee class I have a method called `setPosition(List<Position> positions)` Is there a way to pass a list to this function by getting position array from BSON using `emp.get("positions")

Below is the getAllEmployees() funtion where I can't set the position by converting the BSOn into a list

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    DBCursor cursor = employeeCollection.find(query);
    System.out.println("cursor.count : " + cursor.count());
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
             DBObject emp = cursor.next();
             Employee employee = new Employee();
             employee.setId((long) emp.get("id"));
             employee.setLocationId((long) emp.get("locationId"));
             DBObject pos = (DBObject) emp.get("position");
             System.out.println("pos : " +pos);
             List<Position> positions = *HERE COMES THE PROBLEM!!!!!*
             employee.setPosition(positions);
             list.add(employee);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Any suggestions how to pass the positions array from mongodb directly to setPosition function?

Comment: I think you never make any attempt to retrieve the position data from the `DBObject` returned in the cursor. There simply is no such call make like `emp.get("position")` which is what is needed to actually get the data. For some reason you are calling `PositionService` when the data is already in the `emp` object. The data is already there to use, but you're not using it. Just take the list from the existing object from the cursor.

Comment: Hi Neil, I am trying to do that. `emp.get("positions")` returns a BSON object right? If I cast it to DBObject and assigned to a variable called `pos` how can I add it to the `employee.setPosition(positions)` which accepts a `List<Position>` type argument

Comment: I'm actually wondering why you are doing any of this really. The driver supports using "typed" queries that marshal the BSON data in and out of your defined classes out of the box. So you seem to be trying to re-invent the wheel here. I think you should look at the documentation further. As for "how to do it in this context", then just 1. get the list. 2. Iterate the list and `.get()` the properties, and feed them to your class, then append to a list of class. 3. Take that list of `Position` and add it to the `Employee`. No need for another query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got this to work. Below is the `getAllEmployees()` function. The solution was to use `BasicDBList` instead of `BDObject`.

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    DBCursor cursor = employeeCollection.find(query);
    System.out.println("cursor.count : " + cursor.count());
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
             DBObject emp = cursor.next();
             Employee employee = new Employee();
             employee.setId((long) emp.get("id"));
             employee.setLocationId((long) emp.get("locationId"));
             BasicDBList positions = (BasicDBList) emp.get("position");
             for (Object position : positions) {
                Position pos = new Position();
                pos.setLatitude((double) ((DBObject) position).get("latitude"));
                pos.setLongitude((double) ((DBObject) position).get("longitude"));
                pos.setTime((String) ((DBObject) position).get("time"));
                employee.getPosition().add(pos);
            }
             list.add(employee);
    }
    return list;
}
```